# Database won't update (double opt-in mailing list)

Tags: php, mysql

very new to PHP and working on a mailing list with double opt-in. I found this code here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?632689-Guide-to-creating-a-double-opt-in-email-list&s=560d4d5d106fde7ccc1a53b507c436cd&p=4350152&viewfull=1#post4350152
and made it work until I click on the link in the e-mail, for some reason it doesn't update the status in the database to "confirmed" (it says "Sorry, account unvalidated").

I can't find the error with my basic knowledge, would appreciate some help!
Thanks a lot
JD

signup.php:

```
<?php
if(true === array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
{
require("connect.php");

$rResult = mysqli_query($conn,
    sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO newsletter2 (email, status)VALUES('%s', 'pending')",
        $_POST['email']
    )
);
mail(
    $_POST['email'],
    'Subscriber Confirmation',
    sprintf(
        'Thankyou, please visit http://****.com/newsletter2/confirmSignUp.php?key=%s to confirm your subscription.',
        sha1($_POST['email'])
    ),
    null,
    null
);
echo 'Thankyou, please check the provided email for a link to confirm your subscription.';
exit;
}
?>
```

confirmSignUp.php:

```
<?php
if(true === array_key_exists('key', $_GET))
{
require("connect.php");

$rResult = mysqli_query($conn,
    sprintf(
        "UPDATE newsletter2 SET status = 'confirmed' WHERE email = SHA1('%s')",
        $_GET['key']
    )
);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
{
    echo 'Thankyou, email confirmed';
}
else
{
    echo 'Sorry, account unvalidated.';
}
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around string values

Comment: Not related to the question. You dont need to do `(true === array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))` just use `(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))`

Comment: String literal values need to be quoted

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Why are you expecting `sha1($_POST['email']` to be that same as `$_POST['email']`

Comment: And in the `confirm.php` you are `sha1()`ing the `sha1`'d hash again. Basically it is not finding the originally inserted row because you are not using the same value in the `email` value as you stored it with

Comment: _Small Note_ SHA1() is a One Way Hash ... emphasising the **One Way** bit

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! I'm afraid I don't really understand the error though :( never used SHA, keys etc before. What do I need to put in the Where clause so it finds the row?

Comment: As for safety, don't worry, it's for a fictional project only. Want to make it work first, then I might try some advanced things with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

signup.php

```
$rResult = mysqli_query($conn,
    sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO newsletter2 (email, status, authkey)VALUES('%s', 'pending', '%s')",
        $_POST['email'],
        sha1($_POST['email']) 
    )
);
```

confirmSignUp.php:

```
$rResult = mysqli_query($conn,
    sprintf(
        "UPDATE newsletter2 SET status = 'confirmed' WHERE authkey = '%s'",
        $_GET['key']
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you! What do I need to put in the Where clause so it finds the email?

Comment: i would say insert SHA1 key in database as authkey. and compare authkey = $_GET['key'] in update.

Comment: What is the value for the SHA1 key when inserting it into the database?

Comment: sha1($_POST['email']) this value you need to store in database.

Comment: I can't get it to work.. I'm sorry for being so clueless :(

Comment: i have updated my answers for you. kindly check it now

Comment: `"INSERT INTO newsletter2 (email, status, authkey)VALUES('%s', 'pending', ?? )",($_POST['email'])`

If I put sha1($_POST['email']) at the end, it stores the key instead of the email address in the database